# Text truncated on start when longer than TextInput size

Tags: android, react-native

Trying to use the Android TextInput component, but the text gets cut off in start when text is longer than the component size.

[image]
Required state

[image]
Actual state

Is there way I can get the text rendered from start or set the cursor at beginning. And only set the cursor to end when this component is focussed or selected ?

Comment: Did you try https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onscroll ?

Comment: How can do I use it for my use case ?

Comment: Could share your code?

Comment: ``` <TextInput
          ref='input'
          disableFullscreenUI={true}
          value={ value }
          maxLength={ this.props.item.length }
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={[styles.container,newStyle]}
          editable={true}
          multiline={this.props.isMultiline}
/>```

Comment: I am facing same issue.